# Javascript и base64

Tags: base64, javascript

Как при помощи скрипта закодировать строку в base64?
 Суть проблемы, в шаблон движка ДЛЕ нужно вставить скрипт который будет обрабатывать дополнительное поле. Раньше я это делал через PHP вставляя код в модуль вывода полной новости

```
$xfieldsdata = xfieldsdataload( $row['xfields'] );

if ($xfieldsdata['smotrimserial']<>''){
    $url=base64_encode($xfieldsdata['smotrimserial']);
    $smotrimserial = <<<JS
    <div id="smotrimserial"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
      var data = {};
      $('#smotrimserial').load( '/engine/modules/play/smotrimserial.php?text={$url}', data );
    } );
    </script>
JS;
}
    $tpl->set('{smotrimserial}', $smotrimserial);
```

Сейчас такой возможности нету и мне нужно переменную которая выводится тегом **[xfvalue_smotrimserial]** при помощи javascript  закодировать в base64 и вставить в скрипт.
Тоесть в шаблон я вставляю код

```
<div id="smotrimserial"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
var data = {};
$('#smotrimserial').load( '/engine/modules/play/smotrimserial.php?text=[xfvalue_smotrimserial]', data );
} );
</script>
```

и мне нужно чтобы в этом коде [xfvalue_smotrimserial], было закодированым...
Как такое решить?
Скажу сразу в javascript полный НОЛЬ! Так что сильно не пинайте )))

Comment: Второй вопрос должен быть вынесен в отдельный вопрос согласно правил форума. Никаких UPDATE. Откатываю. Тем более я дал на него ответ в комментах.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как это ни странно, но Google знает все.
В JavaScript есть готовые функции atob и btoa (Проверил их работу в пяти браузерах последних версий- они есть, но поговаривают, что в старых версиях IE и Opera их может не быть).
Аналогичный вопрос на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript) с сниппетами в ответе.
Base64 как [jQuery плагин](http://plugins.jquery.com/base64/).
Сам поисковый запрос простой как 2 копейки [google:javascript base64](https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+base64&hl=ru).

Comment: спасибо **ReinRaus**, теперь вопрос второй, как правильно в моем случаи сипользовать jQuery плагин?

Comment: Скачиваете плагин и после подключения jQuery делаете подключение  jquery.base64.js в HTML-коде страницы.

Comment: я выше, в самом вопросе описал, что именно мне не ясно
такая строка тоже не пашет (
$('#smotrimserial').load( '/engine/modules/play/smotrimserial.php?text={$.base64.encode("[xfvalue_smotrimserial]")}', data );

Comment: Попробуйте сначала встроенные функции atob и btoa без использования плагина, если проблема воспроизведется- Вы что-то не так делаете.  
Если не воспроизведется- Вы неправильно подключаете плагин.  
Первый раз вижу такую конструкцию:  

    {$.base64.encode("[xfvalue_smotrimserial]")}
Насколько мне известно в jQery нет такой плюшки и надо будет записать нормальный код:  

     $('#smotrimserial').load( '/engine/modules/play/smotrimserial.php?text='+$.base64.encode("[xfvalue_smotrimserial]"), data )